# Django Urlconf Named Groups String Matching

Tags: python, regex, django, urlconf

I'm trying to match two strings in an url, but it's not working out likely due to my poor knowledge of regex. I want urls like the following:

- testserver/username/
- testserver/username/1234/
- testserver/username/rewards/

Username would be passed in to the url as a kwarg. Here's what I have:

```
url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$', Posts_Index, name="userposts"),
url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/photos/$', Photo_Index, name="userphotos"),
url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/rewards/$', Rewards_Index, name="userrewards"),
url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/following/$', Follower_Index, name="userfollowers"),
url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/followers/$', Following_Index, name="userfollowing"),
url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', SinglePost_Index, name="singlepost"),
```

However, only userposts will be found. If I try to query userphotos or anything below userposts, only the userposts url will be checked, which obviously leads to failure. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: in the rewards url there isn't a  `/` symbol at the last. And also to match one or more numbers, you need to use `\d+`, `\d` matches only a single digit.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks for spotting that. When you say there isn't a / symbol at the last for the rewards url, I'm assuming you're talking about the desired urls I listed. Then yeah. But in the urlconf, the / is present. Will edit it though, I guess.

Comment: i think `testserver/` would be added automatically. Am i correct?

Comment: @AvinashRaj , Correct, I'm just concerned with what comes after testserver

Comment: Post the whole urlpatterns variable please

Answer (score 0):

From the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/): `Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.`

Thus if you reverse the order of the urls it should work better.